# How can I retrieve the e-mails from my shared folders in Dropbox?

Tags: email, dropbox, file-sharing, ipad

I am using Dropbox to share lots of documents with my clients as I meet with them.  It's also a great way to grab their email address. So I have been doing this for about a month now and wanted to circle back with the clients in which I have shared documents. But, I can't find their email addresses on my Dropbox app for iPad. Are they on my mail server or are they on the Dropbox app?

Answer (score 2):

Without using any kind of [API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), from where you'll probably able to get the e-mail of your shared folders, you can check the e-mail from the web interface.

Since there is no such thing as contact list here, you can do the following:

1. Login to [Dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com)
2. Go to `Sharing` tab
3. Enter any folder and click on `Shared folder options` button
4. Once you're there click on the `Members` tab
5. Finally by clicking on the names there you can send them e-mail, and it's using your native client :)

Another way of checking your "list of shared e-mails" is to create a folder, again from the WebUI, then click on the `Share a folder` and when you start typing the autosuggestion kicks in. I don't know how many mails do you have, but you can test all the letters (they are not too many) and it really depends on how important this is for you, to go through all that hassle.

Comment: +1 This is the only way I could think of without using an API (kudos on mentioning the API as well).